# Why deletion of element of embedded subdocument array using Mongoose JS isn't working?

Tags: node.js, arrays, database, mongodb, mongoose

1.) I have two models: Project and Action:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ProjectSchema = new Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  title: { type: String, default: "default project title" },
  deadline: { type: Date, default: "2099-01-01T10:30" },
  description: { type: String, default: "default project description" },
  actions: [],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Project", ProjectSchema);


const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ActionSchema = new Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  type: { type: String, default: "none" },
  queued: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  description: { type: String, default: "default description" },
  complete: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  waitingFor: [],
  setting: { type: String, default: "default setting" },
  deadline: {type: Date, default: "2099-01-01T10:30"}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Action", ActionSchema);
```

2.) I have a service to `destroy` an `Action` which should **both** update `Project` actions subdocument array (i.e. delete the action) and delete the `Action` from its collection.

It receives an id of the Action to delete from the array.

3.) I've tried several approaches but the closest I've gotten is:

```
require("../db");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Action = require("../models/action");
const Project = require("../models/project");

const destroy = async (id) => {
  const filter = { _id: id };
  const action_id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id);
  const project_id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5fdcd4fdc0d61b7fe59f0940");

  Project.updateOne(
    {},
    {
      $pull: { actions: { _id: id } },
    },
    {
      arrayFilters: [{ "i._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) }],

      new: true,
    }
  ).then((output => console.log("output of db op: ", output)))

  Action.deleteOne(filter, function (err, output) {
    console.log("output of db op ", output);
  });
};
```

The deletion of `Action` from its collection works but `Project` does not update its actions array. Currently, the output of the above is:

output of db op:  { n: 1, nModified: 0, ok: 1 } (It finds `Project` but doesn't update!

output of db op  { n: 1, ok: 1, deletedCount: 1 } (Successfully deletes from Action collection, but Project array is unmodified)

Any suggestions for how to successfully update `Project` is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pull operator sometimes doesn't work properly in MongoDB so you can try it with an update and provide the ids directly as objectIDs in the query. Also, you need to provide the id of the project you are trying to update in the update one.

```js
 Project.update({ _id: ObjectId(project_id ) },

    { $pull: { actions: ObjectId(action_id ) } },

    { new: true }, function (err, source) {
      if (!err) {
console.log('Source log',source);
Action.deleteOne(filter, function (err, output) {
    console.log("output of db op ", output);
  });
}
else{
console.log('Error in deleting projects and actions')
}

});
```

Comment: including Project ID query param did it (I thought mongoose would hunt it down based on the action ID, bad assumption). The reason "0 modified" is because it was looking for an action in the first project in the collection and not finding an action matching the ID. Thanks!